# WCF Service activation exception with very uncommon reason

Tags: wcf, exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_itds5u52, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_itds5u52, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The first time I deployed it worked ok.
The second time and since then, it gives me ServiceActivatioException win accessing the services and I get the error above when browsing to the service.svc page.

How can I solve this?
I am using WCF tracing, I don't know if it matters.

```
 <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="~/Logs/1OperatorMessagesLog1.svclog" />
```

Thank you,
Ryan

Comment: Are you use you have the 'App_Web_itds5u52' assembly referenced in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and rebuild solved it...